# errors trying to commit to vuex store

Tags: vuejs3, vuex

im stuck. i was following a tutorial to add a simple login system for a school project. but im stuck when the vuex `this.$store.commit(stuff)` returns this error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'commit') TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'commit')`

Following is the code

Login.vue :

```
methods: {
    login() {
      //make sure username OR password are not empty
      if (this.input.username != "" || this.input.password != "") {
        this.output = "Authentication complete"
        //stores true to the set_authentication and username to the set_username
        this.$store.commit(`auth/${SET_AUTHENTICATION}`, true);
        this.$store.commit(`auth/${SET_USERNAME}`, this.input.username);
        this.$store.commit(`auth/${SET_ACCES}`, 1);
        this.$store.commit(`auth/${SET_USERID}`, 10);
        this.output = "Authentication complete."
        this.$router.push('/test')
      } else {
        this.$store.commit(`auth/${SET_AUTHENTICATION}`, false);
        this.output = "Username and password can not be empty"
      }
    },
  },
```

Mutations.js:

```
import {
    SET_ACCES,
    SET_AUTHENTICATION,
    SET_USERID,
    SET_USERNAME
} from "../storeconstants";

export default {

    [SET_AUTHENTICATION](state, authenticated) {
        state.authenticated = authenticated
    },
    [SET_USERNAME](state, username) {
        state.username = username
    },
    [SET_ACCES](state, acces) {
        state.acces = acces
    },
    [SET_USERID](state, userid) {
        state.userid = userid
    }
}
```

and the state the mutations.js is using

```
import getters from './getters';
import mutations from "@/store/auth/mutations";

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state() {
        return {
            authenticated: false,
            username: "",
            acces: 0,
            userid: 0,
        }
    },
    mutations,
    getters
}
```

I would apreciate any help